# Getting "reserved word 'function’" when trying to define coffee script function

Tags: function, coffeescript, focus

I have this coffee script

```
@open_login_dialog = () ->
  opt = {
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: 'auto',
    focus: function(e) ->
      $(this).dialog('option', 'width', $("#loginBox").width())
  }
```

Rails is reporting the cryptic error, “SyntaxError: [stdin]:184:12: reserved word 'function’”.  It doesn’t tell me a line, but when I comment out the “focus:function” part everything works, which leads me to believe that’s the culprit.  How do I write the above so that it plays nicely with coffee script?

Comment: You have the right syntax just above where you define `@open_login_dialog`.

Comment: Still not working.  I changed the line beginning with "focus:" to "focus = (e) ->" and got the error "SyntaxError: [stdin]:184:11: unexpected =".

Comment: Well, the error says it all. You need to use `:` for assignment inside an object, while `=` is assignment to a variable. What @muistooshort meant is that you should use `() ->` instead of `function`.
So the line should read `focus: (e) ->`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @muistooshort's comment, You need to use coffeescript function syntax, which replaces `function(a,b,c)` with `(a,b,c) ->`

Secondly, you need to continue using `:` for assignment inside an object.

I would also suggest brushing up a little on coffeescript. This is my [favourite resource](https://arcturo.github.io/library/coffeescript/) on the language. A linter would also help to catch these basic syntax errors.

Your code can be further cleaned up:

```
@open_login_dialog = ->
  opt = 
    autoOpen: false
    modal: true
    width: 'auto'
    focus: -> 
      $(this).dialog 'option', 'width', $('#loginBox').width()
```

### Explanation

1. If you don't expect any parameters, you can leave out the `()` from the function definition and just use the arrow `->`.
2. You don't need `{}` brackets to define an object
3. When defining an object over multiple lines, there is no need for trailing commas
4. You aren't using the [eventObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) `e` in the focus listener, so that can be left out too.
5. Parenthesis are optional when calling functions and passing them parameters.